# Android global variables, getter, setter, error,

Tags: java, android, global-variables

I try this to add some data to "global variables". Class "Conection" without window in void

```
for (int in = 7; in < arAll.length; in++) {
        if (arAll[in].toString().endsWith("/")) {
            ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setPath(arAll[in]
                    .toString());
        } else {
            ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setFile(arAll[in]
                    .toString());
        }
```

MyApplication getter's and setter's:

```
private ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();


public void removeAll() {
    this.file.clear();
    this.path.clear();
    this.all.clear();

}

public int len() {
    return this.all.size();
}

public String getStrbyId (int i) {
    return this.all.get(i).toString();
}

public ArrayList<String> getFile() {
    return this.file;
}

public void setFile(String file) {
    this.file.add(file);
    setAll(file);
    Log.v("",file);
}

public ArrayList<String> getPath() {
    return this.path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path.add(path);
    setAll(path);
    Log.v("",path);
}
public ArrayList<String> getAll() {
    Log.v("",String.valueOf(len()));
    return this.all;
}

private void setAll(String all) {
    this.all.add(all);
}
```

In manifest  `<application android:name="MyApplication"`

When I try to execute first void, I have an error.

Comment: @user625565: can you pls post what's the error, you had got in your Logcat??

Comment: don't see where you initialize your 'MyApplication' with onCreate()... or post the entire code and the logcat entrys

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables/708317#708317 . You can try using  `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @user625565: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at LogCat and examine the stack trace associated with your error.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are using global variables via the Application context very likely that there is something improperly designed in your app.  You should not need to use global variables like this at all, and it may be a potential source of your error (passing around the context and getting access to these global variables is sometimes necessary, but perhaps not in this situation).  Instead what you should do is pass the necessary variables between components and use them within each component.  (Activity, Service, ContentProvider.)  So perhaps instead of trying to get this hacky thing working, you could rethink why you need global variables.